# What comes next in this sequence? Choose from 4 options

Tags: sequence

What comes next in this sequence? Why? Choose from the 4 options.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is

> 3 - EM

Each line is

> A number encoded in binary, translated to Roman numerals, and then written as it is pronounced.

So to find the answer:

> EYE = I = 1
>  EX = X = 10 = 2
>  EXEYE = XI = 11 = 3
>  SEE = C = 100 = 4
>  ...
>  SEEEXEYE = CXI = 111 = 7

And finally

> The next number is
>  8 = 1000 = M = EM